# Project: A chipps challenge-esque game in Java libgdx

Tags: java, android, project, libgdx

Me and 5 friends are making a game for android with libgdx and the Android development kit. The game is going to be Chipps Challenge-esque in design. However we are uncertain what would be a good structure for the classes and such. Or if there is a tool to help out making the levels. Some kind of gridbased tileprogram sounds good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for level design use tilemaps

but do use libgdx 0.9.9 nightlies

http://dpk.net/2011/05/01/libgdx-box2d-tiled-maps-full-working-example-part-1/

http://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/TiledMaps

and as per tile map editor us can use "Tiled"

http://gamedev.tutsplus.com/tutorials/level-design/introduction-to-tiled-map-editor/